# Cannot convert divider in responsive design

Tags: css

I have created a template which have the page divided in two sections, when I display the site in a desktop resolution all works well, but when I run the site on a smartphone I get the half circle on top and the divider between the two images, not responsive:

[image]

Essentially the half red circle, should be reduced in a smartphone resolution, and the divider goes outside the two images, this is what I tried so far:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .divider{
        top: 14.5%;
        left: 50%;
        height: 64.2%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    .circle{
        top: -45%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .logo{
        top: 0.5%;
        left: 22.5%;
    }
}
```

the problem's that this doesn't cover all the resolution case, so the problem is not fixed at all.

Is there a way to handle all the resolutions and make that template really responsive?

[This is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0jpe1u2/).

SNIPPET:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

/*Overlay*/
.hovereffect {
  width: 50%;
  height: 90vh;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  background: #a7151f;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

.hovereffect img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90vh;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: none;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.hovereffect h2:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.hovereffect a,
.hovereffect p {
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a,
.hovereffect:hover p,
.hovereffect:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 16px;
}

/*DIVISORE*/
.middle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.divider {
  border-right: 5px solid #a7151f;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 14.5%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 76.2%;
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.circle {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: -250px;
  left: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #a7151f;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #a7151f;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.first {
  background-image: url('https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-pro/assets/img/dg1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.second {
  background-image: url('https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-pro/assets/img/bg9.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.logo {
  top: 2.5%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 41.5%;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-pro/assets/css/material-kit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>
      Site
    </title>
  </head>

  <body class="sections-page sidebar-collapse">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="first">
            <div class="overlay">
              <h2>First</h2>
              <p>
                <a href=#">Explore</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <span class="divider"></span>
          <img class="img-responsive center-block circle">
          <span class="circle">
          </span>
          <img src="#" class="logo" style="z-index: 9999">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="second">
            <div class="overlay">
              <h2>Second</h2>
              <p>
                <a href="#">Explore</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-xl-between">
            <div class="col-6">
              <div class="copyright text-center text-xl-left text-muted">
                © 2019 <a href="#" class="font-weight-bold ml-1 pul-left" target="_blank">Credit</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <div class="row">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link pull-right" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link pull-right" target="_blank">Terms & Conditions</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This time, your code's not in the question. Part of it is - the CSS. But without the HTML on which it acts, it's not really reproducible. Again, you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do what you did in jsfiddle.net here on Stack Overflow, so it should just be three copy and pastes away...

Comment: Please let us know what your expected result should be.

Comment: @EternalHour I added the snippet to as suggested by Heretic Monkey, essentially I would make the divider (which is red line separator between the images) responsive (now goes outside the row) and also the red circle on the top should be responsive, so it must adapt the size based on the resolution screen

Comment: It makes sense that the divider shouldn't expand beyond the row. But what size should the red circle be in relation to the images?

Comment: @EternalHour I doesn't have a specific size, but the rule is this: the red circle should not cover the images as widely as now. Depending on the screen resolution, the red circle should be displayed, but I still need to be able to view the images, for example above I uploaded an image here: https://imgur.com/a/eMktFwL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of layout can be achieved with Flexbox with many fewer lines of code. Also, much less HTML markup is required.

Total responsiveness is achieved combining the flexbox behavior with relative units (`%`, `vh`, `vw`).

I put several comments in the CSS to explain what each rule is doing.

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.the-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh; /* fill the screen */
  width: 100vw; /* fill the screen */
}

.the-circle {
  position: absolute; /* overlap the pics, removes it from the box flow */
  background-color: #a7151f;
  border-radius: 50%; /* rectangle becomes an ellipse */
  width: 60vw;
  height: 30vh;
  top: -15vh; /* half of the height */
  left: 0; /* these 3 lines... */
  right: 0; /* ...keep the "circle"... */
  margin: auto; /* ...centered at the top */
}

.the-image-wrapper {
  display: flex; /* easy responsive columns */
  height: 100%; /* fill the screen */
}

.the-image-wrapper > div {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* items inside the wrapper will grow to fit avilable space */
}

.the-image-wrapper > div.the-divider {
  flex: 0 1 5px; /* this divider item will not grow, and will be 5px wide */
  background-color: #a7151f;
}

.first {
  background-image: url('https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-pro/assets/img/dg1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.second {
  background-image: url('https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-pro/assets/img/bg9.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-container">
  <div class="the-circle"></div>
  <div class="the-image-wrapper">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="the-divider"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this has helped me much. Just a question: I tried to add a logo inside the red circle, but this is not displayed, why? I simply created an `img` tag

Comment: The top half of the circle is out of view due to negative margin-top. Add padding-top to that div equal to the amount of negative margin-top and you should see your image.

Comment: thanks for the hint! I got half of the work, infact the result is too bigger than expected, this happen only when the resolution is low, I have created a fiddle for you, if you want take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcj42tgv/

Comment: This is as much help as I can give on your original question. If you are having new issues perhaps create a new question for that.